# Dashboard with Multi Series Bar Chart

Tags: community, dashboard, analytics

I've created a bar chart summing up revenue for the month of Dec 2014 and Jan 2015.  It looks fine when a bar chart is added in report mode but when added to my dashboard it only display one data set.  Why is that and how can I show the multi series bar chart in my dashboard?

Thanks

Comment: screen shots are helpful here with dashboard issues - show screenshot for both report and dash (blur out any sensitive numbers)

Comment: The chart below is what I would like to see when added to my Dashboard.  [link](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s197/sh/0408e1f0-2bed-4d5d-a71e-0ebf3032bae7/7da15eb9b2ceaee857a5779bc59b20b8) but once added to my dashboad, only one data series is shown.